# Data structure for fast random access and sequential access in R^3 (x,y,z)

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I want to find a memory efficient data structure for searching through a huge network of R^3 coordinates maybe 100,000-500,000 coordinates. I have looked at k-d tree which looks good is there any good data structure for fast random and sequential access out there? The programming language will be C++ or C. I have looked into k-d - tree and R^*-tree is there some more efficient data structure out there?

**id   x    y    z**

1   0.1  0.05   0.3

2   0.3  0.22   2.3

3   0.1  0.2    3.3

and so on

Comment: What exactly kind of queries do you need from the structure? For fast sequential and random access `std::vector` would suffice.

Comment: I want to search with given (x,y,z) coordinates and it should be memory efficient. I don't think std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >; would be that efficient for sequential and random access.

Comment: @Marcus I meant something like `std::vector<point_3d>`. It is the best way for sequential and random access. If you want to search for a point, this is just other problem. Since you do not actually use the geometric nature of the data, simple `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` will do good job.

Comment: When you say "search with (x,y,z)", do you mean for exact match, or for near match.  The latter is *much* harder.   Please clarify what you want to do with the data structure.  "random access" is unclear.

Comment: Consider using your graphics card to solve your problems. Shaders can work on 3D data points in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to search within an arbitrary rectangular prism, you should consider an octree.  Wiki has an article on it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

Comment: Thanks for answer! if I want to store decimal points in the octree and search with given coordinates is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is method how to most quickly and memory effectively find existance of point through all of them or organize map with it.
You need to implement special comparision object http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less for yor 3d coordinate class. An use it as template param for std::map or std::vector dependenty of your access requirements.

```
template< class T >
struct My3DLess;
bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y && lhs.z < rhs.z;
}

typedef std::map<My3DPoint,MyMappedObject,My3DLess> My3DMap;
```

If your insert is not such frequently as fetch you need to use vector. You can use this sorted insert function:

```
typedef< typename T, typename Pred >
typename std::vector<T>::iterator
    insert_sorted( std::vector<T> & vec, T const& item, Pred pred )
{
    return vec.insert ( std::upper_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), item, pred ), item );
}

typedef std::vector<My3DPoint> My3DVector;
My3DVector my3DVector;

// inserting
insert_sorted( my3DVector, my3DPoint, My3DLess() );

// check existance
if ( std::binary_search( my3DVector.begin(), my3DVector.end(), my3DPoint, My3DLess() ) )
    { ... }
```

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: What exactly kind of queries do you need from the structure?  @lisyarus have ask you? I have show how to most quickly and memory effectively find existance of point through all of them or organize map with it.

Comment: The queries i need is to search with a given (x,y,z) coordinate and maybe by given id. Search with sequential and random access should be possible. Since its a huge amout of coordinates its important with good memory efficiency

Comment: The most memory effectively method is using array as I have show. But Insertion into them must be sorted. Sorting is need too mutch cpu resource. It is not good when point array frequently updated. You need to select what is best for you. Map (more memory, quick insert) or vector (more quick search).

Answer (score 0):

If memory efficiency is paramount, I would recommend something like the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (my own implementation). Depending on the amount of data and the dimensionality, it requires LESS space than a plain `float[]` or `float[][]` which contain the same coordinates (for example 10M points and >7 dimensions). For 3 dimensions it requires more space but still less than most other data structures.

It is a mix of quadtree/octree with a trie (prefix-sharing) and some additional algorithms to make it fit for large data and high dimensions.

Added benefit: Supports very fast random updates, they take hardly longer than look-ups. Query speed is comparable with R-Trees and similar.

Major drawbacks: There is currently no C/C++ version, only a Java version. Also, the code is quite complex and requires some work to translate. Another drawback is that the PH-Tree is sometimes a bit slow with small datasets with <1,000,000 points; it may get faster(!) with more points.

**EDIT**
Sequential access returns a stable ordering. As added bonus, sequential access and window-queries return result in z-ordering. However, ordering by ID is not possible.

Comment: is that something like multi-dimensional trie? if it is, I believe lookup complexity is O(key length), that can be greater than O(log N) for trees. I've seen tries perform a lot worse than trees.... if you can key floats, do you have a hash table based solution?

Comment: I think most multi-dim tries (with `k` dimensions) simply interleave the bits and store them in a binary tree, i.e. O(64*k), which is of course slow. The PH-Tree performs much better because for most internal operations it can get rid of the `k` and is also much below the '64' in O(64*k), assuming k<60. It has far fewer nodes than other multi-dim tries. It can insert 100,000,000 entries in a tree in about 100 secs on a desktop machine. There is a PH-Tree implementation for the ELKI framework, it shows that, for example, kNN queries have very competitive performance.

Comment: To be honest, 1us per insert doesn't sound very fast. But I'm not accustomed to containers of 100M entries. A hash table can do 2 orders of magnitude better (with a small entry). This is an interesting problem. I think a hash-table-based solution would be a lot faster, but there's the problem of keying floats and it'd use more memory

Comment: 2 orders of magnitude faster is a lot, that's about 60 cycles per insert... . Hashmaps are indeed faster for pure insert/lookup (which is what was asked), but can't do geometric queries. They also consume much more space than the PH-Tree does (that was a requirement by the OP). In the link above there is a PDF called PhTreeRevisited, in Figure 6 it shows that the tree is barely affected by the number of entries, especially for clustered datasets. For small datasets, if kNN & window queries are not required and memory is secondary, I wouldn't use it, otherwise I think it's worth having a look.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I'm looking into 3d space and want to map coordinates to a specific id its possible to do this in PH-tree?

Comment: The PH-Tree works like a Map, that means you can use a 3D coordinate as key and any object, also an ID, as value.